# How can I insert a space in between a group of alpha characters and numeric character?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

How can I replace `Python3` and `Python2` with `Python (3|2)` using Atom Editor's find and replace?

So far I have tried these expressions:

```
find: Python[0-9]
replace: Python $1

find: Python[0-9]
replace: Python $1

find: Python[^\s](.*?)\s
replace: Python $1 

find: Python+[0-9]
replace: Python $1
```

Unfortunately none of them work as expected and some *literally* replace the `2` or `3` with `$1`.

Could somebody please shed some light as to why each expression did not work and what I was doing wrong?
I would like to get a better understanding so it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
find: Python([23])
replace: Python $1
```

You have to capture (in the find) the portion that you will want to replace, and then reference that with $1 in the replace.

You can also use this to find 2 capture groups and replace them both:

```
find: (Python)([23])
replace: $1 $2
```

Comment: I'm testing it now, I was away from this site for a bit.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the answer, it works great. It looks like my problem was that I was not using the the parenthesis correctly. Thank you again for the time and effort you put in to this answer. Unfortunately I've reached my daily voting limit :D I'll come back for that later ;)